# Test selecting checkboxes using webdriverio and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, checkbox, webdriver-io

I am trying to test selecting checkboxes using webdriverio along with mocha, and chai.

Below is what I tried in a `javascript` module pattern

```js
select_checkbox: function(browser, key, value){
  return browser.isSelected(key, value, 'tab')
},
```

I am calling this method inside a `promise.each` loop and submitting the form

```js
...
     return reagents_utils.select_checkbox(browser, "#id_category_0", "Instrument");
}).then(function(){
    browser.saveScreenshot('./snapshot.png');
}).then(function(){
  return reagents_utils.submit_form(browser);
});
```

Here is a snapshot of tests showing that the checkbox is not selected and hence the submission fails!

[image]

How can test selecting the checkbox next to Instrument using webdriverio and javascript? I made sure that I am referencing the correct selector (id).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of webdriverIO are you using? It looks like the 'isSelected' function only takes one argument (the locator), but you are passing 3 arguments.

Also, isSelected returns a boolean and doesn't actually select the check box. You can probably .click() the check box to select it. 
[webdriverIO API docs - isSelected](http://webdriver.io/api/state/isSelected.html)
[webdriverIO API docs - click](http://webdriver.io/api/action/click.html)